# Response header image in 2017 theme

Tags: themes, css

I know this is an older theme but is perfect for what i needed to do on this website. The set up is perfect except that the header image does not reduce on mobile devices using the theme without changes, causing the image of the candidate to be off the screen. I was helped with this css

```
@supports (object-fit:cover) {
 .has-header-image .custom-header-media img {
   object-position: center left;
}
```

which aligns the artwork to the left that does show the image of the person but this is only a temporary fix (I hope) because the flag does not display

Can someone provide CSS to reduce the image to fill the screen and look like the images below? Or CSS to replace the header with a different image (I can create one where the photo is centered. Any assistance greatly appreciated as other than this the site is done.

FYI I tried the following and it does not work (found through a search)

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 800px ) {
   #masthead.site-header {
      background-size: auto 100%;
   }
}
```

The page I need help with: https://brendanlawler4dc.org/